# How to expand an array while debugging in visual studio code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, watch

This is my code, its a simple code block for permutation:

```
void arrange(char c[], int N, int start)
{
    if (start == N)
    {
        print(c, N);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i < N; i++)
    {
        swap(c[start], c[i]);
        arrange(c, N, i + 1);
        swap(c[start], c[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char c[] = { 'A','B','C' };
    int N = (sizeof(c) / sizeof(char));
    arrange(c, N, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Its not giving the output I expect and I wanted to debug this code.
I wanted to observe the character swaps in the input array. But when I
debug, the input array cannot be expanded.

Comment: In the watch window use `c,10` or however many entries you want to display.

Comment: Alternatively, for simple `char`s, memory window shows exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that `c` in function `arrange` is not an array. It is just a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 25):

If you have an array `t` that is pointed to by `p`, like this:

```
double t[5] = {0,1,2,4.5,2.3};
double *p = t;
```

You can watch `p` on the debugger if you recast it.
Just write on the watch window:

```
(double[5]) *p
```

Comment: what if I debug C program, not a C++ program

Answer (score 10):

When adding a beak point in `arrange()` then the c array shows it's address`0x7fffffffdd15` like this:

[image: Problem]

To solve this on the bottom left you should see the WATCH section.
Add <your_array_name>, <array_length> like this:

[image]

Now in the watch section you should see your array like this:

[image]

Comment: Easiest way! BTW, where did you found this magic?